# How to get the language modeling loss by passing 'labels' while using ONNX inference session?

Tags: pytorch, huggingface-transformers, language-model, onnxruntime, gpt-2

When using GPT2 we can simply pass on the 'labels' parameter to get the loss as follows:

```
import torch
from transformers import GPT2Tokenizer, GPT2LMHeadModel

tokenizer = GPT2Tokenizer.from_pretrained('gpt2')
model = GPT2LMHeadModel.from_pretrained('gpt2', return_dict=True)

inputs = tokenizer("Hello, my dog is cute", return_tensors="pt")
outputs = model(**inputs, labels=inputs["input_ids"])
loss = outputs.loss
```

But, not able to find out how to get the same loss in an ONNX inference session. I am using the below code which only returns the 'last_hidden_state':

```
import onnxruntime as ort

from transformers import GPT2TokenizerFast
#tokenizer = GPT2TokenizerFast.from_pretrained("gpt2")

ort_session = ort.InferenceSession("onnx/gpt2/model.onnx")

inputs = tokenizer("Using BERT in ONNX!", return_tensors="np")
outputs = ort_session.run(["last_hidden_state"], dict(inputs))
```

Answer (score 0):

How "onnx/gpt2/model.onnx" was generated?

It looks like while the PyTorch run uses `transformers.GPT2LMHeadModel`, the ORT run uses `transformers.GPT2Model`, which is a "bare GPT2 Model transformer outputting raw hidden-states without any specific head on top" and doesn't return loss.

Comment: Hi, I used MyGPT2LMHeadModel in Gpt2Helper.py to generate 'model.onnx' and saved it using export_onnx method.

```
from onnxruntime.transformers.gpt2_helper import Gpt2Helper, MyGPT2LMHeadModel
from transformers import AutoConfig

model_name_or_path = "gpt2"
config = AutoConfig.from_pretrained(model_name_or_path, cache_dir=cache_dir)
model = MyGPT2LMHeadModel.from_pretrained(model_name_or_path, config=config, cache_dir=cache_dir)
device = torch.device("cpu")
model.eval().to(device)
onnx_model_path = "onnx/gpt2/gpt2.onnx"
Gpt2Helper.export_onnx(model, device, onnx_model_path)
```

Comment: I was able to make a change in GPTLMHeadModel's forward() method to send 'labels = input_ids' which returned "loss" as the first output and it helped solve my problem.